# jQuery validate: Using remote validation causes error styling to be removed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

When using a remote rule and the validation passes for that rule, if any other fields are invalid, they show error messages, but have the error styling removed. If I remove the remote rule, everything works correctly. Also, if the remote validation fails, everything works correctly. This problem only occurs the first time the validation is run - after the first time, everything works correctly.

What it looks like (notice the error messages are there, just not red):
[image]

What it *should* look like:
[image]

If the remote validation fails, everything works correctly:
[image]

Javascript:

```
$("#CreateUserForm").validate({
    rules: {
        UserName: {
            remote: "/Users/UsernameIsFree"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        UserName: {
            remote: "Username is taken"
        }
    }
});    


//bootstrap styling for errors
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateUserModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span></span>x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create User</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="CreateUserForm">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Full Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>School</label>
                                <input type="text" name="School" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Username</label>
                                <input type="text" name="UserName" class="form-control" value="GeneratedDefault" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="CreateUserBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">Create User</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.17.0

Comment: Never heard of this before and it seems totally unrelated to anything you've programmed.  It might be a new bug.  You should post this on the developer's GitHub page, otherwise, I'm not sure how SO would be able to do anything to help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove unhighlight function and try,

```
//bootstrap styling for errors
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Great thanks it worked for me. Why it does behave like that though?